# Doxygen: How to avoid including C++ class source code in the generated html files?

Tags: doxygen

I've created the doxygen project with doxygen wizard for my C++ project. I've found that my header class source code is included in the html documentation. I'd like to avoid this. These files are *_8h_source.html . I can remove the references to the Files section but I'd like remove these files also.
I tried to play with the following options but these files are still there.

```
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES=xx
EXTRACT_ALL=xx
```

Doxygen version: 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display of the header files is a complicated issue and depending on a.o. the setting of `SOURCE_BROWSER` and `VERBATIM_HEADERS`.
The documentation of:

> SOURCE_BROWSER
>
> If the SOURCE_BROWSER tag is set to YES then a list of source files will be generated. Documented entities will be cross-referenced with these sources.
> Note: To get rid of all source code in the generated output, make sure that also VERBATIM_HEADERS is set to NO.
>
> The default value is: NO.

and

> VERBATIM_HEADERS
>
> If the VERBATIM_HEADERS tag is set the YES then doxygen will generate a verbatim copy of the header file for each class for which an include is specified. Set to NO to disable this.
>
> See also
> Section \class.
>
> The default value is: YES.

See: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html

Setting both `SOURCE_BROWSER` and `VERBATIM_HEADERS` to `NO` will result in the required output.